# Accuray error due to Index column in dataframe

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I hope you guys are in good health. I am working on keras library python 3 for solving a regression problem. When i load my dataset into a panads dataframe it adds index column automatically which can be reset but cannot be removed when I train my model on that dataset it gives very low accuracy (0.002) Will you guys please help me to this problem Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import keras 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from subprocess import check_output
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))

dataset=pd.read_csv("../input/Concrete_Data_Yeh.csv")
dataset=pd.read_csv("../input/Concrete_Data_Yeh.csv")
data=dataset.drop(["flyash"],axis=1)
msk = np.random.rand(len(data)) < 0.8
train = data[msk]
test = data[~msk]
y_train=train[['csMPa']]
x_train=train.drop(["csMPa"],axis=1)
y_test=test[['csMPa']]
x_test=test.drop(["csMPa"],axis=1)
no_of_colums=x_train.shape[1]

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu',input_shape=(no_of_colums,)))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=20)
prediction=model.predict(x_test)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: can you show the output of dataset.head(5)

Comment: IMO `'accuracy'` is NOT a good metric for the regression problem, try to use `'mae'` or `'mse'`. DataFrame's index values will __not__ be used by the model, so you don't need to warry about them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest use,

`df = df.values`

df now becomes the numpy ndarray:
this will effectively remove the index column and the column names, so what you would do is as follows

```
y_train=train[['csMPa']].values
x_train=train.drop(["csMPa"],axis=1).values
```

now i am not saying that this will improve your accuracy, but as you asked it will remove the index column, this might help your situation and anyways passing the data this way is better

NOTE: Accuracy as a metric for regression is not right, accuracy is better suited for classification, you shouldnt set the metric as accuracy, you may use something like MSAE, you may refer to https://medium.com/usf-msds/choosing-the-right-metric-for-machine-learning-models-part-1-a99d7d7414e4

Focus on minimizing the error, rather than maximizing the accuracy, you maximize accuracy in classification, not in regression